# merging two videos by coding

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-2

i m developing a site in Codeigniter, PHP and HTML5.

In my project I want to merge two videos, i.e. first video canvas will larger in size and second video canvas will smaller than first one and will appear above the first video in bottom left corner.

Is there any solution to merge two vidoes by coding, or by simply using HTML5?

Please Guide me on it.

Sorry for my English and please let me know if you get my point or is it difficult to get because of my poor English?

Comment: You can CSS position over each other so they are visually merged. Ohterwise you should probably start to better describe what merging two videos means for you. Drawing a picture works, too ;)

Comment: i mean that i want to combine two vidoes in single one.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a watermark, you'll probably want to embed it in the video. There are a lot of CLI watermark tools out there that should help you with that.

I don't think you can do this in HTML5, as videos don't usually support transparency.

Comment: Well, you could try setting `opacity: 0.5` in CSS, but that's not overlaying, that's merging, and most likely not what you want ;-) But no, other than that I don't think there's a way.